# CSS: position absolute has conflicting screen width with position fixed in chrome when there's a vertical overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, css-position

I am currently programming a site with a video banner set to fixed positioning in the background, and a div that has absolute positioning slightly covering part of the video on the bottom half. The problem is however, once I add this second div with absolute positioning, the width of the screen becomes bigger under the condition there is a vertical overflow on the screen contained within this div, which in turn messes up the video sizing.

Here is my code:

```html
   <div class="row" style="height: 5%;">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="background-color: black; box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px #000000; z-index:5; padding:0;">
            Search
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid video" style="height:70%; z-index:5; padding:0; margin:0;">
    <div class="row" style="padding:0; margin:0; height: 100%;">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12" id="video-container" style="background-color:white; height:100%; padding:0; margin:0;">
            <video autoplay="" loop="" style="position: fixed; right:0px; bottom: 0; min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; transform: translateX(calc((100% - 100vw) / 2));">
                <source src="beats/titlescreen.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid header" style="background-color: red; position:absolute; height:100%;">
This is a test
</div>
```

Since I set a height of 100% in the last div seen in the above code, there is a vertical overflow on the page which makes the width slightly bigger than if there was no overflow (if you take away the 'height: 100%;' tag this will become apparent).

I am unsure why this happens, and why it is solely contained to Chrome. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

is it posible to give the body an `overflow: hidden;`

```html
<body style="overflow: hidden;">
<div class="row" style="height: 5%;">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="background-color: black; box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px #000000; z-index:5; padding:0;">
            Search
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="container-fluid video" style="height:70%; z-index:5; padding:0; margin:0;">
    <div class="row" style="padding:0; margin:0; height: 100%;">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12" id="video-container" style="background-color:white; height:100%; padding:0; margin:0;">
            <video autoplay="" loop="" style="position: fixed; right:0px; bottom: 0; min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; transform: translateX(calc((100% - 100vw) / 2));">
                <source src="beats/titlescreen.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid header" style="background-color: red; position:absolute; height:100%;">
This is a test
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: When I add overflow:hidden, the problem is somewhat fixed, however then I can not scroll down to see the content in the final div. If I do overflow-x:hidden, then the problem isn't fixed at all (same with overflow-y:hidden).

Answer (score 0):

So after much playing around with, I have come to the conclusion that somehow the issue was due to having padding:0; along with left:0; and right:0; on the first div. I am not sure how this caused the issue, perhaps something to do with bootstrap? Anyway, thanks for the help guys!